# Pass url of asset to service worker for it to cache

Tags: javascript, web-worker, service-worker

My CSS and JS have hashs in the filename for versioning, What is the best way to pass the url of theses assets to the service worker so that it can cache them?

Comment: In the future, please put forth some effort to provide some code showing what you have already tried. To get started, try something like [this article](https://medium.com/@philipp.schaechtele/asset-caching-with-service-worker-c40dcda43842).

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using a build-time tool to generate either just the "manifest" of URLs that your service worker needs, or alternatively, the full service worker. This will play nicely with the service worker update flow—when one of your files change, the underlying service worker will change as well, triggering a new pair of `install`/`activate` events.

A few options to consider:

- [`offline-plugin`](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin) (Webpack specific)
- [Workbox](https://workboxjs.org/), specifically, the `workbox-build`/`workbox-cli`/`workbox-webpack-plugin` modules, depending on your build system.
- [`sw-precache`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache)/[`sw-precache-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/goldhand/sw-precache-webpack-plugin) (similar, but older, than Workbox).